# valgrind on arm SIGILL due to opensll

Tags: memory, arm, valgrind

I am trying to analyze my application which is running on `arm` with Valgrind. I am using `ssl` and `libcrypto` inside it. So on attempt to analyze it I am receiving `SIGILL`.

I've tried to disable it

```
--sigill-diagnostics=no
```

but it does not help.

I also tried to intercept the signal from within an application itself by
adding

```
signal(SIGILL, SIG_IGN);
```

to the very start of my application. This does not help as well.

I've tried adding suppression file. But this also does not resolve an issue.

Is there any other methods to get valgrind running on arm with ssl ?
Is it possible at all to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem as described by @unresolved_external on an `ARMv7` based platform. Even calling valgrind with parameter `--sigill-diagnostics=no` in the right order did not help:

```
valgrind --sigill-diagnostics=no /path/to/your/program
```

`valgrind`s output complained about to different illegal instructions:

- `0xEBAD 0x1CCA` and
- `0xEC51 0x0F1E`.

With further internet research I found patches for both unhandled instructions on https://bugsfiles.kde.org:

1. `0xEBAD 0x1CCA`
   discussion: https://together.jolla.com/question/205808/help-unable-to-profile-app-with-valgrind/
   patch: https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=108118
2. `0xEC51 0x0F1E`
   discussion: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344802
   patch: https://bugsfiles.kde.org/attachment.cgi?id=113735

Compilation of `valgrind` using both patches resolved any error message when analyzing my executable linked to OpenSSL libcrypto.so.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefule with the argument order :

> valgrind --sigill-diagnostics=no your_prog